# I am building a quotes generator. How do I SHOW a randomised sample of my seeds?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

OK, so first question: do I need an `index` function in my Controller? This would call `.all` method on my Class? Can I do away with this?
Would a `show` function in the Controller suffice?
In which case, the function reads as follows?

```
def show
    @quotation = Quotation.find(params[:id])
end
```

And consequently, on the `show.html.erb`:

```
<div class="card-category">
<%= @quotations.text %>
<button>
    <%= link_to "More ➜", quotation_path%>
</button>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can google your type of database to see the best way to select a random record. For example, in postgreSQL...

```
@quotation = Quotation.order('random()').take
```

For something database-independent...

```
@quotation = Quotation.find(Quotation.pluck(:id).sample)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need an index function in my Controller?

No, it is not necessary. But don't forget do delete it from routes if you want to disable it.

```rb
  resources :quotes, except: :index
```

> This would call .all method on my Class?

You can do whatever you want.

> Can I do away with this?

But if you want it to be in common way, it should respond with *many* resources.

> How do I SHOW a randomised sample of my seeds?

I think the best option would be is to have another controller action for this

```rb
def random
  # ...
end
```

And a route to your `routes.rb`.

```rb
  get '/quotes/random', to: 'quotes#random'
```

Answer (score 0):

for the short just use:

```
Quotation.find(Quotation.ids.sample)
```